# AWK find if line is newline or #

Tags: bash, unix, search, awk, newline

I have the following, it's ignoring the lines with just # but not those with \n (empty/ just containing newline lines)

Do you know of a way I can hit two birds with one stone? 
I.E. if the lines don't contain more than 1 char, then delete the line..

```
function check_duplicates {

awk '
  FNR==1{files[FILENAME]}
         {if((FILENAME, $0) in a) dupsInFile[FILENAME]
          else
            {a[FILENAME, $0]
             dups[$0] = $0 in dups ? (dups[$0] RS FILENAME) : FILENAME
             count[$0]++}}
              {if ($0 ~ /#/) {
                  delete dups[$0]
               }}
 #Print duplicates in more than one file
         END{for(k in dups)
            {if(count[k] > 1)
              {print ("\n\nDuplicate line found: " k) " - In the following file(s)"
                print dups[k] }}
         printf "\n";
      }' $SITEFILES

awk '
NR {
    b[$0]++
   }
       $0 in b {
          if ($0 ~ /#/) {
          delete b[$0]
                        }
                     if (b[$0]>1) {
                     print ("\n\nRepeated line found: "$0) " - In the following file"
                     print FILENAME
                     delete b[$0]
                     } 
   }' $SITEFILES

 }
```

The expected input is usually as follows.

```
 #File Path's
 /path/to/file1
 /path/to/file2
 /path/to/file3
 /path/to/file4



 #
 /more/paths/to/file1
 /more/paths/to/file2
 /more/paths/to/file3
 /more/paths/to/file4
 /more/paths/to/file5
 /more/paths/to/file5
```

In this case, /more/paths/to/file5, occurs twice, and should be flagged as such.

However, there are also many newlines, which I'd rather ignore.

Er, it also has to be awk, I'm doing a tonne of post processing, and don't want to vary from awk for this bit, if that's okay :)

It really seems to be a bit tougher than I would have expected.

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: As an aside you may want to improve your formatting so you can easier follow program flow.

Comment: Also is this a full program as you never appear to set dups array up or add anything to it? Actually i can't work out what you are trying to do at all in this script? Can you post the problem this script is supposed to solve?

Comment: Updates above. I want to ignore the # and \n chars, can't get the \n ones to ignore though.

Comment: Awk cannot see the `\n` as by default it is the RS and is discarded when the record is read. The way to check an empty line is `/^$/` or `/^[[:space;]]*$/` if there can be spaces.

Comment: Thanks again guy's, this is answered :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine both the `if` into a single regex.

```
if ($0 ~ /#|\n/) {
    delete dups[$0]
}
```

OR

To be more specific you can write

```
if ($0 ~ /^#?$/) {
    delete dups[$0]
}
```

**What it does**

- `^` Matches starting of the line.
- `#?` Matches one or zero `#`
- `$` Matches end of line.

So, `^$` matches empty lines and `^#$` matches lines with only `#`.

Comment: Thanks, beautifully written, but it doesn't seem to work at all within awk.

Comment: @BenCoughlan It would be much easier for people to answer if you can include include and example input and expected output. The awk scrip that you provided seems to contain some extra lines which may be avoided.

Comment: The input is pretty generic, but it's above.

Comment: Thank you so much @nu11p01n73R really a fantastic tutorial.  Thanks again :D